# Handling C array in Python, a crash

Tags: python, c++, arrays, fedora-25

I have a C++ library, handling the reading and processing of DAB data (prety large, multithreading)
I am writing (trying to write) a Python interface for that. The interface contains some callbacks, one for the audio. That one is called from within the library with as parameters a C array with PCM samples, the number of samples and the samplerate. To "transfer" the data to the Python interface the C array is "Python"-ed, and the C callback calls then a Python function (the reference of which is passed earlier on)

The question is that I am probably doing something wrong since the library - when called from Python - crashes on precise the PyArray_SimpleNewFromData  call.
To me - a newby in Python - it would seem that a C library containing the implementation of PyArray_SimpleNewFromData (which actually seems a macro) is missing (the error is consistently a segmentation violation.

If so, is there a library that I am missing (and where to find that?)

My system:
Fedora 25, 64b
Python 3.5

```
void    callback_audio (int16_t *b, int size, int rate) {

    PyObject *arglist;

    PyObject *result;

    PyObject *theArray;

    PyGILState_STATE gstate;

    npy_intp dims [1];

    dims [0] = size;

    if (size == 0)
        return;

    gstate  = PyGILState_Ensure ();

    theArray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData (1, dims, NPY_SHORT, (void *)b);

    arglist = Py_BuildValue ("Oh", theArray, rate);

    result  = PyEval_CallObject (callbackAudio, arglist);

    Py_DECREF (arglist);

    Py_DECREF (theArray);

    PyGILState_Release (gstate);

}
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If you were missing the definition of PyArray_SimpleNewFromData, you would have a compiling error.  If you're getting a segmentation violation, this issue is likely entirely a C++ issue.  Does `b` look like a valid pointer?  Are you sure that `size` is not set too big?  If it's the memory-size of `b`, then maybe you need to set `dims[0] = size/sizeof(int16_t)`?

Comment: Solved. It turned out that I should have called "import_array ()" in the initialization. So, the numpy/array part was not initialized

Comment: Comments on Stack Overflow are considered ephemeral; they aren't guaranteed to exist from one point to another.  You should write up (and later accept) a detailed answer to this.  The goal of questions in Stack Overflow is to not only solve your problem, but help people in the future who have a similar problem.  Self-answering is allowed, and doing so will make it more clear that your problem had a solution (as well as giving you a bit of reputation and ensuring that the answer is available in a more permanent field.)